# Удаление из обьекта JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var filterData = {
  items: []
};


$('.a').change(function(){

  if (this.checked == true) {

    const attrData = [];
    let filterItem = filterData.items.find(el =>
      el.taxonomy === this.name
    );

    if(filterItem) {
      filterItem.terms.push(this.value);
    } else {
      filterData.items.push({
        taxonomy: this.name,
        terms: [this.value],
      })
    }

    console.log(filterData.items);
  } else {
      let filterItemDel = filterData.items.find(el =>
      el.taxonomy === this.name
    );

    let iNum = filterItemDel.terms.indexOf(this.value);

    delete filterItemDel.terms[iNum];
  }
});
```

Записывать получаеться , а удалить заставить не могу.

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//delete filterItemDel.terms[iNum];
filterItemDel.terms.splice(iNum, 1);
```