# Как обрабатывать клик по li только верхнего уровня

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть менюшка вида:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Some Link</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li>Link 2end Level</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Some Link 2end</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li>Link 2end Level</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Рабочий JS

```
jQuery(function($){

        $('ul.main-menu li').each(function(e){

        $(this).click(function(event){

          event.preventDefault();

          if (e === 35 || e === 18 || e === 17 || e === 34) {
            $('ul.sub-menu').addClass('asx');
          }

          else {
            $('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('asx');
          }

          if ($(this).hasClass('menu-item-has-children')) {

            if ($(this).hasClass('active-nav')) {

              let subUla = $(this).find('ul').first();  

              $(subUla).css({
                'margin-top': '-100%',
                'display': 'none',
              });

              $('.nav-wrapper').css({
                'margin-bottom': '0',
                'transition': '0.3s',
              });

              $(this).removeClass('active-nav');

            }

            else {

              let subUl = $(this).find('ul').first();  

              $('ul.main-menu').find('.active-nav').removeClass('active-nav');

              $('ul.main-menu').find('.sub-opened').css({'display': 'none'});

              $(this).addClass('active-nav');

              if ($(subUl).css('display') === 'block') {
                $(subUl).css({
                    'margin-bottom': '-100%',
                    'display': 'none',
                });
              }

              else {

                let subUld = $(this).find('ul').first(); 

                $(subUld).css({'display': 'block'});

                let subMenuHeight = $(subUld).innerHeight() + 30;

                $(subUld).addClass('sub-opened');

                $(subUl).css({
                  'margin-top': '20px',
                });

                $('.menu-main-menu-container').css({
                    'margin-bottom': subMenuHeight,
                });

                $('.nav-wrapper').css({
                  'margin-bottom': subMenuHeight,
                  'transition': '0.3s',
                });

              }
            }
          }

          else {

            let subMenuHeightClose = $('.hovered-menu').height();

            $('.nav-wrapper').css({
              'margin-bottom': '0',
              'transition': '0.3s',
            });

            $('ul.sub-menu').css({
                'margin-bottom': '-100%',
                'display': 'none',
            });

            $('.menu-main-menu-container').css({
                'margin-bottom': '0',
            });
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Сейчас когда меню открыто ( ul.sub-menu ) при клике на li из него закрывается все меню, а мне нужно обрабатывать событие только у верхнего уровня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.main-menu > li').click(function(event) {
  // account for event bubbling:
  if ($(event.target).closest(".sub-menu").length)
    return;
```

`.each(` - не нужен.

Comment: Но у меня 6 элементов в меню верхнего уровня

Comment: @НикитаРязанов Это очень хорошо ). Им всем будет назначен обработчик `click`.

Comment: все равно при клике ul.sub-menu > ul > li у меня sub-menu закрывается

Comment: @НикитаРязанов Потому что Вы выбираете `$('ul.sub-menu').`, а надо `$(this).find('ul.sub-menu')`.

Comment: не совсем понял где использовать: $(this).find('ul.sub-menu') )))

Comment: @НикитаРязанов там, где Вы манипулируете классом `"asx"` - какие-то из действий, видимо, имеется в виду выполнять только с `"ul.sub-menu"` внутри кликнутого `"li"`.

Comment: я asx сейчас вообще убрал, но все равно вложенные li отрабатывают click

Comment: @НикитаРязанов Вы добавили проверку `event.target` в начало обработчика?

Comment: нет ) Уже добавил , все ок. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @НикитаРязанов Пожалуйста. Успехов! Не забывайте принимать ответы ) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869702/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-js

Comment: ответ на вопрос принял )